# Where can I find the actual code WP/Gutenberg stores for my changes?

Tags: wordpress, edit, gutenberg-blocks

I'm fairly new to wordpress, using the Gutenberg block editor, TT1 theme.  I'm more used to html/css but I need a shopping cart and chose wooCommerce....
I have searched high and low, but can't find exactly where my changes are stored. Some say in the database, but not where or how (the _options table has stuff, but e.g., I can't find 'footer' or 'group').

For example, the first element in my footer is a group. In the editor, no background color has been chosen for that group (and groups blocks have no background). But it unexpectedly has a white background.  Dev tools show a class of has-white-color.

I think looking at my template changes would help me figure this out - so my question is - how do I find my changes (for this and other issues)?